# How to obtain the high frequency dispersion relation for transverse waves in the Drude model?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, dispersion

**Context**

I am studying electrodynamics using Zangwill [1].  I have a narrow question regarding a proposition found there in.  In the section on the Drude model of conducting matter that applies to particles with mean travel time $\tau$, a characteristic plasma frequency $\omega_p$, the Fourier transform of the permittivity, $\hat{\epsilon}(\omega)$, the Fourier transform of the permiability, $\hat{\mu}(\omega)$, and frequency parameter $\omega$.  Adjusting from what Zangwill writes in [1], the proposition is that

> In the high frequency limit when
> $$\frac{\hat{\epsilon}(\omega)}{\epsilon_o}\approx 1 - \frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2} \quad (\omega\,\tau \gg 1)$$
> is valid, the dispersion relation for transverse waves
> $$k(\omega) = \omega\sqrt{\hat{\mu}(\omega)\,\hat{\epsilon}(\omega)} = \frac{\omega}{c}\,\hat{n}(\omega)$$
> reads
> $$
> \boxed{\omega^2 = \omega^2_p + c^2\,k^2 .}\tag{1}
> $$
> I have made several attempts to maniupulate these and other equations to obtain (1). Yet, I come up short.

**Question**

The narrow question here is, how does one derive the high-frequency (or collisionless) dispersion relation, i.e., Eq.(1), for transverse waves using the Drude model?

**Bibliography**

Zangwill, Modern *Electrodynaics*, 2013 pp. 630-632 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispersion relation follows from a simple substitution of your first equation into the second. The square of the 2nd equation gives
$$ k^2 = 
{\omega^2 \over c^2}{\epsilon \over \epsilon_0}
$$
Substituting the 1st equation
$$ k^2 = 
{\omega^2 \over c^2}{(1-{\omega_p^2 \over \omega^2})}
$$

$$ \omega^2 = {\omega_p^2+k^2 c^2}
$$
Edit based on comments about refractive index:

I am not sure what is troubling you regarding refractive index. Look at  your 2nd equation. If you eliminate $\omega$, you have the definition of  refractive index.
$$n(\omega) = c \sqrt{\epsilon(\omega) \mu(\omega)}$$
$$n(\omega) = \sqrt{{\epsilon(\omega) \mu(\omega)} \over {\epsilon_0 \mu_0}}$$
With the usual assumption of non-magnetic media, $\mu(\omega)=\mu_0$ , then
$$n(\omega) = \sqrt{{\epsilon(\omega)} \over {\epsilon_0}}$$
Also note that the ratio, $\epsilon(\omega) / \epsilon_0$ is called the relative permittivity or dielectric constant.